# How to make NSMutableArray and NSDictionary display results in UI

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I am creating an app that requires users to input data into a `UITextField` which is then passed to an api from my website. The api returns data in XML form. The app is parsing the XML feed that is returned from the API without trouble. My question, then, is how can I take that data and display it in my UI? The data is books with images. I have created a "bookshelf" similar to the iBooks bookshelf. I want to display my images on this bookshelf, but I don't know how many there will be. The number of returned results depends on the query of the API. I can limit the results per "shelf" if need be. Do I need to layout `UIImageView`s and make them update with the data? If so, how do I get them to update?

Answer (score 2):

First try to break down your question into individual question since this question consists of lots of questions like:

- UI Designing (TableViewController & it;s delegate methods)
- Data Structure
- XML/JSON Parsing i.e depends on the response of your API
- Image Parsing
- Updating the whole UI.

I think nothing better than this would help in this case :

*This sample demonstrates a multi-stage approach to loading and displaying a UITableView. It begins by loading the relevant text from an RSS feed so the table can load as quickly as possible, and then downloads the images for each row asynchronously so the UI is more responsive.*

[Lazy Loading](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html)

Comment: I only have one major question. I want to display the results on screen, but not in a UITableView. I wanted to display the results in a "bookshelf" type screen. The response from the API is XML and organizes products as follows                                               <item id="UNIQUEID"><title>TITLE</title><author>AUTHOR</author><image>URL OF IMAGE</image><price>PRICE</price><bind-type>BINDTYPE</bind-type></item>

Answer (score 0):

When you are parsing the xml data you must be storing those data into NSMutableArray.
Use that array for displaying data ie images.
for eg:
model *object=[appDelegate.mutableArray objectAtIndex:intVal];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.image]];